# Can an optimizing compiler add std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, move-semantics, rvalue

Can a compiler do **automatic lvalue-to-rvalue conversion** if it can prove that the lvalue won't be used again?  Here's an example to clarify what I mean:

```
void Foo(vector<int> values) { ...}

void Bar() {
  vector<int> my_values {1, 2, 3};
  Foo(my_values);  // may the compiler pretend I used std::move here?
}
```

If a `std::move` is added to the commented line, then the vector can be moved into `Foo`'s parameter, rather than copied.  However, as written, I didn't use `std::move`.

It's pretty easy to statically prove that my_values won't be used after the commented line.  So s the compiler allowed to move the vector, or is it required to copy it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The compiler is required to behave as-if the copy occurred from the `vector` to the call of `Foo`.

If the compiler can prove that there are is a valid abstract machine behavior with no observable side effects (within the abstract machine behavior, not in a real computer!) that involves moving the `std::vector` into `Foo`, it can do this.

In your above case, this (moving has no abstract machine visible side effects) is true; the compiler may not be able to prove it, however.

The possibly observable behavior when copying a `std::vector<T>` is:

- Invoking copy constructors on the elements.  Doing so with `int` cannot be observed
- Invoking the default `std::allocator<>` at different times.  This invokes `::new` and `::delete` (maybe<sup>1</sup>)  In any case, `::new` and `::delete` has not been replaced in the above program, so you cannot observe this under the standard.
- Calling the destructor of `T` more times on different objects.  Not observable with `int`.
- The `vector` being non-empty after the call to `Foo`.  Nobody examines it, so it being empty is as-if it was not.
- References or pointers or iterators to the elements of the exterior vector being different than those inside.  No references, vectors or pointers are taken to the elements of the vector outside `Foo`.

While you may say "but what if the system is out of memory, and the vector is large, isn't that observable?":

The abstract machine does not have an "out of memory" condition, it simply has allocation sometimes failing (throwing `std::bad_alloc`) for non-constrained reasons.  It *not* failing is a valid behavior of the abstract machine, and not failing by not allocating (actual) memory (on the actual computer) is also valid, so long as the non-existence of the memory has no observable side effects.

A slightly more toy case:

```
int main() {
  int* x = new int[std::size_t(-1)];
  delete[] x;
}
```

while this program clearly allocates way too much memory, the compiler is free to not allocate anything.

We can go further.  Even:

```
int main() {
  int* x = new int[std::size_t(-1)];
  x[std::size_t(-2)] = 2;
  std::cout << x[std::size_t(-2)] << '\n';
  delete[] x;
}
```

can be turned into `std::cout << 2 << '\n';`.  That large buffer must exist *abstractly*, but as long as your "real" program behaves as-if the abstract machine would, it doesn't actually have to allocate it.

Unfortunately, doing so at any reasonable scale is difficult.  There are lots and lots of ways information can leak from a C++ program.  So relying on such optimizations (even if they happen) is not going to end well.

---

<sup>1</sup>  There was some stuff about coalescing calls to `new` that might confuse the issue, I am uncertain if it would be legal to skip calls even if there was a replaced `::new`.

---

An important fact is that there are situations that the compiler is *not* required to behave as-if there was a copy, even if `std::move` was not called.

When you `return` a local variable from a function in a line that looks like `return X;` and `X` is the identifier, and that local variable is of automatic storage duration (on the stack), the operation is implicitly a move, and the compiler (if it can) can elide the existence of the return value and the local variable into one object (and even omit the `move`).

The same is true when you construct an object from a temporary -- the operation is implicitly a move (as it is binding to an rvalue) *and* it can elide away the move completely.

In both these cases, the compiler is required to treat it as a move (not a copy), and it can elide the move.

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
  return x;
}
```

that `x` has no `std::move`, yet it is moved into the return value, and that operation can be elided (`x` and the return value can be turned into one object).

This:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
  return std::move(x);
}
```

blocks elision, as does this:

```
std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<int> x) {
  return x;
}
```

and we can even block the move:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
  return (std::vector<int> const&)x;
}
```

or even:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
  std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4};
  return 0,x;
}
```

as the rules for implicit move are intentionally fragile.  (`0,x` is a use of the much maligned `,` operator).

Now, relying on implicit-move not occurring in cases like this last `,` based one is not advised: the standard committee has already changed an implicit-copy case to an implicit-move since implicit-move was added to the language because they deemed it harmless (where the function returns a type `A` with a `A(B&&)` ctor, and the return statement is `return b;` where `b` is of type `B`; at C++11 release that did a copy, now it does a move.)  Further expansion of implicit-move cannot be ruled out: casting explicitly to a `const&` is probably the most reliable way to prevent it now and in the future.

Comment: Do you have any links where I can learn more about how this works or how the abstract machine is defined?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Find a copy of the C++ standard?  [Here is one draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf).  [Here is another](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf).  The behavior of C++ is specified in the standard in terms of an abstract machine.

Comment: I'll add that due to separate compilation, `::operator new` can be replaced in a different translation unit that is then linked in, so omitting the call is tricky without whole-program knowledge. Also, the coalescing rule applies to new-expressions, not direct calls to `::operator new`, which is what `std::allocator` does.

Comment: Your second example of blocking elision (returning a parameter) probably does not actually block elision (depends on the precise definition of the word 'local' which is never defined in the spec -- are parameters 'local'?).  However, most implementations are probably unable to elide this case anyways, even if the spec says it is legal, unless they inline the function.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I remember it not being allowed in the standard, but I don't have the quote, and may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the great response!  A follow-up question: do you know of any compilers that actually *do* perform this optimization?

Comment: @edward with sufficient inlining and whole program optimization?  I think I have seen allocations eliminated, but would not swear to it.  Basically it isn;t very practical, except when you eliminate the `Foo` call entirely.

Comment: @m.m. first 3 paragraphs are pretty explicit yes?  (Sorry deleted last comment).  Rest is justification and elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the compiler could move out of `my_values`.  This is because that causes no difference in *observable behaviour*.

Quoting the C++ standard's definition of observable behaviour:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

Interpreting this slightly: "files" here includes the standard output stream, and for calls of functions that are not defined by the C++ Standard (e.g. operating system calls, or calls to third party libraries), it must be assumed that those functions might write to a file, so a corollary of this is that non-standard function calls must also be considered observable behaviour.

However your code (as you have shown it) has no `volatile` variables and no calls to non-standard functions. So the two versions (move or not-move) must have identical observable behaviour and therefore the compiler could do either (or even optimize the function out entirely, etc.)

In practice, of course, it's generally not so easy for a compiler to prove that no non-standard function calls occur, so many optimization opportunities like this are missed. For example, in this case the compiler may not yet know whether or not the default `::operator new` has been replaced with a function that generates output.